# Graph Calendar - Difference in the response returned by EWS and Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have developed an application using EWS Calendar.
I am migrating from EWS to Graph.

I'm stuck at Graph Calendar's Get event handler.
The response between EWS and Graph is similar. However, there are some EWS fields that I can't find at Graph.

Those fields are:
**RoutingType, AppointmentState, DisplayCc, Displayto, ExtendedProperty**

DisplayCc, Displayto: Can I replace it with [attendees]?

RoutingType, AppointmentState, ExtendedProperty: What field can I replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

You can requests the corresponding MAPI properties:

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(id eq 'Integer {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8217') or (id eq 'String 0x0E03') or (id eq 'String 0x0E04'))
```

Comment: Thank you, @dmitry-streblechenko.
I got ExtendedProperty.

But the other 4 fields I can't get yet.
Is there another method to get them?

Comment: The query above specifies 3 fields (I don't know what `RoutingType` is). What are those fields? Can you see them in OutlookSpy if you click the IMessage button?